# Sass Cache ruining SCSS Values

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

when integrating Bootstrap in SASS Version into my project I came along with a strange error where some CSS Rules seemed to not apply or even wrong.
It took me hours to figure out that its actually caused by the SCSS Compiler which created an .scss-cache. If I let the Compiler create the CSS file newly (after deleting the cache folder) everything works, but as soon as I do a SCSS Change, it apparently loads information out of the cache with strangely flattened values, sometimes even completely changed hex colors and font sizes.

I thought of the precision in the SASS Installation to be the problem and changed the number.rb like that:

```ruby
def self.precision
  @precision ||= 10
end
```

That didnt change the issue tho. I could change SASS such that it doesnt create any caches, but there has to be a better way to do that.
I really dont get why such strange phenomena occur in the css files.

Here are some of those btw:

```
-/* line 353, C:/Users/Weidler/CloudStation/git/GitHub/thegreatdictation/code/scss/../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss */
+/* line 353, ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss */
 .form-group-lg .form-control {
-  height: 36px;
+  height: 46px;
   padding: 10px 16px;
-  font-size: 14px;
-  line-height: 1;
+  font-size: 18px;
+  line-height: 1.33333;
   border-radius: 6px;
 }
-/* line 360, C:/Users/Weidler/CloudStation/git/GitHub/thegreatdictation/code/scss/../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss */
+/* line 360, ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss */
 .form-group-lg select.form-control {
-  height: 36px;
-  line-height: 36px;
-}
-/* line 365, C:/Users/Weidler/CloudStation/git/GitHub/thegreatdictation/code/scss/../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss */
+  height: 46px;
+  line-height: 46px;
+}
+/* line 365, ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss */
 .form-group-lg textarea.form-control,
 .form-group-lg select[multiple].form-control {
   height: auto;
 }
-/* line 368, C:/Users/Weidler/CloudStation/git/GitHub/thegreatdictation/code/scss/../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss */
+/* line 368, ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss */
 .form-group-lg .form-control-static {
-  height: 36px;
-  min-height: 28px;
+  height: 46px;
+  min-height: 38px;
   padding: 11px 16px;
-  font-size: 14px;
-  line-height: 1;
-}
-
-/* line 382, C:/Users/Weidler/CloudStation/git/GitHub/thegreatdictation/code/scss/../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss */
+  font-size: 18px;
+  line-height: 1.33333;
+}
+
+/* line 382, ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss */
 .has-feedback {
   position: relative;
 }
```

+ means its in the working file
- mean its in the not working file
nothing means its in both files

Comment: Why did you modify number.rb when there is a precision flag for Sass?

Comment: Cause i didnt know that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did actually not find a Solution that satisfied me a 100% but I got it working for me. The problem appears to be the fact, that Scout, my application I use to live-compile sass/scss code, uses an old version of sass, such that you cant modify the precision or whatever.

When though changing to Koala (another app, which lets you even choose the sass version/compiler) everything worked fine.

So it seems to be a Scout Problem, sadly that software isnt updated anymore too. Tbh Koala seems ways more sophisticated anyways.